# iframe tag is not working in android webview

Tags: android, html, iframe, webview

I have an webview in which I want to load amazon affiliate marketing product link by the loadDatawithBaseUrl method of the webview. Here is my whole html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&OneJS=1&Operation=GetAdHtml&MarketPlace=IN&source=ss&ref=as_ss_li_til&ad_type=product_link&tracking_id=bong27-21&marketplace=amazon&region=IN&placement=B07PBBV3FC&asins=B07PBBV3FC&linkId=bb7e0fb22dc94808b84a34252eca6dff&show_border=false&link_opens_in_new_window=true"></iframe></body></html>
```

I can't understand why but the whole html page is working fine in any browser .But whenever I try to load it with the loadDataWithBaseURL method of Android webview. It is not working.It only shows a blank page.Can anyone tell me what is wrong here ?